# Converting non numeric String to a double value

Tags: string, double, numeric, type-conversion

**Program:**
Type in 2 month names and find the average rainfall

**How I want the flow of the program to work:**
I want the user to be able to type in Jan or Feb and for it to locate the pre-assigned values

**example:** 
double Jan = 2.4;
double Feb = 2.1;

Then output the average between the two.

I looked extensively around on here and other websites and cannot find a possible way to do this.

/*
Type in a month name:
Type in second month name:

The average rainfall is:
*/

Comment: Put the code that you have done until now! This way we will be able to help you! Nobody will do your homeworks!

Comment: @Oscar Bralo - It's not homework, its something in general so I can apply it to later programs. I can give you code but it wouldn't be necessary since I'm trying to understand the concept of this process.

Answer (score 0):

Probably set up an array with the month name as the index. Ex. $varFall['Jan'] = 2.4; $varFall['Feb'] = 2.6 Then you can access the value you want by selecting an array indexed with the month submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the idea I'm going to test out some code on it and see how it runs.